# Nginx: "Resource temporarily unavailable" using a Samba share

Tags: nginx, samba

I am developing on a **Nginx** web server with a **Samba** share.

Whenever I edit a CSS or JS file, I got this error when I reload my website (F5).

> 2012/04/18 11:15:38 [crit] 29607#0: *47708 open() "/var/www/[...].js"
>   failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable), client: 192.168.[...],
>   server: [...], request: "GET [...].js HTTP/1.1", host: "[...]",
>   referrer: "http://[...]"

I need to refresh another time and the errors disappear.

[I found here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,191155) that somebody has the same problem had me which can be caused by **F_SETLEASE**, but I couldn't find how to finally solve this problem.

Any clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These two settings solved the same problem for me:

```
oplocks = no
level2 oplocks = no
```

Comment: This worked for me too. It's worth noting that these are settings for your Samba share, to be added to each share's section in /etc/samba/smb.conf.

Comment: This has been bugging me for quite some time now(basically for the past year almost)... The solution worked indeed. To complete @dgmdan's comment - those sections would most-likely be located at the end of the file(as long as you haven't tweaked it much).

Comment: This fixed the same behavior for me. Thanks!

Comment: These settings could be added to the [global] section of the /etc/samba/smb.conf file. That way you would add them once for all shares.

Comment: user can find this param too kernel oplocks = no